# Jenkins Job execution : Could not resolve host: github.com

Tags: docker, jenkins, dns

Im using docker to start jenkins server, so i tried to execute a job that require to pull from github but it's cannot resolve any host names (github.com,....), this is the error message :

```
    stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/**/**.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

do have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Passing dns settings with `--dns="8.8.8.8"` to the container while using `docker run`
2. Configure the DNS of the docker daemon itself this file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` by adding the following:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```